# Push notification in nestjs with react as frontend as I am not able to find any source or libraries with source code

Tags: reactjs, push-notification, notifications, nestjs

Any article or any blog or example related to the problem will also help

Comment: You can use [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/server-sent-events) supports it.

Comment: It's not immediately clear what you're asking for. A push notification is usually understood as a notification delivered to mobile phones, but what you seem to be asking for is events delivered to your front end react client, which could be accomplished by websockets but Server Sent Events are probably a better fit if you don't need bi-directional communication.

Comment: Yes push notification for mobile devices but i also need hel in desktop for notification as i have  not done it before